# What is max length for column and table names in H2 DB?

Tags: h2

For my project it's necessary for me to know maximum length of name in H2. Unfortunately I can't find in internet. So the question - what is max length for column and table names in H2 DB?

Comment: http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#limits_limitations took all of about 10 seconds to google.

Comment: @Marc B Thank you. I really couldn't find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From marc-b’s comment above: you can find the limits here: http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#limits_limitations

Regarding column and table name maximum lenghts, quoting from this document:

> There is no limit for the following entities, except the memory and storage capacity: maximum identifier length (table name, column name, and so on); […]